# Altium: Including Text of Evaluated Parameter in Value of Second Parameter

Tags: schematics, altium

I would like to include the text value of one parameter in the value of a second parameter. In my case, I am trying to add on the text from the schematic SheetNumber parameter to the end of the text of the schematic DocumentNumber parameter.

In other words, suppose the DocumentNumber parameter is populated with "ABCD" and the SheetNumber is "2". I want to populate the DocumentNumber parameter dynamically with "ABCD-2" (or "ABCD-1", "ABC-3", etc depending on the value in SheetNumber).

It would be nice  if there was a way for a parameter to be evaluated while within a second parameter, like "DocumentNumber-=SheetNumber" but this does not work. Is there a way to do this in Altium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, we do something similar with variants for our boards. In our case, we append the variant name to the end of the document number, but it should work the same with any schematic parameters.

The way we do it is by editing the `DocumentNumber` parameter in the Parameters tab within the Document Options window, the same way you're inputting the base `DocumentNumber`. In that field, enter the following:

`='ABCD-'+SheetNumber`

Now wherever the `DocumentNumber` parameter is used, it should appear as a string formatted per your specification (i.e., "ABCD-2", "ABCD-3", etc.) However, I'm not sure how it will behave in situations where there is no value for `SheetNumber`. In our case, if there is no variant defined or the active variant selection is "No Variant", then the string will appear as e.g., "ABCD-[NO VARIANT]". If you want to avoid this, you can always define a custom parameter such as `NumberedDocString` within that same dialog and set its value equal to the following:

`=DocumentNumber+'-'+SheetNumber`

That way, `DocumentNumber` is "ABCD", `SheetNumber` is your current sheet number, and the value of `NumberedDocString` wherever it is used should be formatted as you want it.

Comment: Okay, so this works if you set the parameter using the Document Options parameters tab. I forgot to mention, though, that I have two variants that require this same thing, but each variant has a different base document number. Therefore I am setting the base document number globally using the "Edit Project Variant" window to add the "DocumentNumber" parameter. Your solution does not seem to work in this case

Comment: Okay, I was able to use your solution with a couple of minor modifications. The first was that I changed the variant names to the base DocumentNumber value. For the DocumentNumber parameter for each schematic sheet (through the Document Options dialog) I used the text `=VariantName+'-'+SheetNumber` and this seemed to work. Many thanks!